# How to determine when a root aggregate contains too many one-to-many relationships?

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, ddd-repositories

I am really struggling with the following scenario:

Let's say I have a user aggregate.  A user can create 1+ groups, messages, friends, photo galleries, etc.  Now it seems like groups, messages, friends, photo galleries should each be in their own aggregates groupings.  It seems illogical to create a user entity that contains an IList<> property for each one of these sections as opposed to just having a User property for groups, messages, friends, photo galleries, etc.  Which approach makes the most sense from a DDD perspective?  I am also thinking about entity hydration and it seems to make more sense to get groups, messages, etc. as needed instead of retrieving all from the user entity.  What is the recommended way to handling this scenario?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even without knowing much about your particular business domain, it does sound very wrong to have the `User` class as a sort of God aggregate with everything else underneath it.

Grouping your entities into larger ones with an aggregate root is completely up to how your business works.  For instance, `PhotoGallery` could be an aggregate root with many `Photo` objects underneath it, or both `PhotoGallery` and `Photo` could both be separate aggregate roots.

For example you might run a photo development company, where photos are always collected, handled and processed as a complete `PhotoGallery` (1 aggregate root).

Or you might run a social networking site, where a `Photo` can be shared and used commonly without needing to load the whole gallery (2 aggregate roots).

So it's really up to you and what your business domain dictates.  You can always suck-it-and-see, try things one way and see how it goes, then refactor later.

Comment: Would that look like the following: the user entity would not contain any IList properties to the other aggregates but the other aggregates (i.e. Group, Message, Friend, etc.) would contain a property to the user entity?  To me, this seems to make the most sense organizationally, as I don't see a user creating messages, groups, etc. from a user profile.  Each of the other aggregates relates to a different section on the user interface.

Comment: Your aggregate roots would most likely have collections of other entities and value objects.  For aggregates like friend it may work well for friend to have a reference to a user (the strong coupling would indicate the intent of friends always being the friend of one user), but for objects like messages, coupling messages too strongly to users, which might not be ideal if messages could belong to a remote system, games, or other entities in your domain, etc.